# how virtual memory increases context switching overhead?

Tags: operating-system, paging, virtual-memory, context-switch

What is the difference between context switching approaches used in a system having virtual memory and without virtual memory ?

Comment: I would say that it depends on your system in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch#Performance . There are a lot of things to take into account.

Answer (score 3):

If your system has no virtual memory, you don't need to flush your translation look-aside buffer (TLB) which keeps track of virtual -> physical memory translations during a context switch. The reason you have to do this in a system with virtual memory is because the mappings held in the TLB will most likely be invalidated in a different context.

Comment: I am curious to know, if TLB really exist in machine which does not support virtual memory?